# Android GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Galera precisando muito da ajuda de vocês. Tenho a seguinte situação uma gridview que contem 3 colunas e n linhas em cada célula desta grid exibo três informações todas as três sendo um texto simples(TextView que insiro a partir de um outro xml) estou populando esta grid por enquanto com um arraylist apenas para teste. Gostaria de saber como faço para que no evento click dessa grid(célula em especifica) posso pegar os valores que passei para ela.
exemplo.

a célula possui 3 informações que foram setadas nela.
dia
mes 
ano
 todos em uma unica celula mas quero pegar esses valores separados após o clique.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Esta usando um `Adapter` correto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que precise usar um `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` no seu `GridView`, assim poderá ser notificado quando um item do seu `GridView` for selecionado.

O código seria algo como:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     ListAdapter mAdapter;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(...);

         mAdapter = new MyAdapter(); // Inicialize seu Adapter

         GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(...); // Recupera o GridView

         gv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
         gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 Object obj = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                 // Usar o objeto relativo aquela célula
             }
         });
     }
}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<Object> mItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // Demais metodos necessário

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }
}
```

É claro que simplifiquei bastante o código (deixando apenas o código mais importante), omitindo alguns métodos e código que precisam ser implementados. Porém recomendo a leitura da documentação sobre o [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), e um [tutorial de como atrelar os dados a um `AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html), a classe [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) e a própria classe [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) que tem muitos outros `Listeners` que podem ser úteis.